# How to create models for a specific database in django ?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Whenever a model is created.. it is created in the default database . How can we specify in which database the model should should be created. I looked at custom routers in django documentation but could not understand it. Can anyone provide example with the code.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. This way, it's more likely users on SO can help you.

Comment: The Django documentation on [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#migrate) Has a pretty good explanation of how this is done.

Comment: @Neelik i want to define the database name in the models.py itself like we  can define the table name using db_table='table_name' in class Meta

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases

From the docs

> you must provide a database name each time you run migrate.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --database=<db_name_1>
$ ./manage.py migrate --database=<db_name_2>
```

Comment: thnx .. but can we do it using routers ?